# How do I get unique names for model builder outputs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, erase

[image]I have set up a model that erases designated restricted areas such as Flood zones, SSSI, national parks etc, each erase is linked from the output to the next erase going step by step through all the different restrictions, 12 restrictions altogether.

My first input is called Usable_Parcels_10m_Rail_Line_Editing, what I would like is each erase output to be named as Parcels_10m_Rail_*Restriction* with the restriction part replaced by the specific restriction name from the restriction feature class named as SSSI_Merge, Nat_Parks_merge etc excluding the merge bit?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [inline model variable substitution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm)

Something like Parcels_10m_Rail_**%fc_name%** is what you want. **fc_name** is the variable that stores the names of your restrictions feature classes.
**Parse Path** can be used to retrieve feature class name.

Comment: Hi I have added a picture can you explain how the parse path and inline variable substitution would work in my model?